# Ban myself/enforced break userscript

Tags: script

Answer to [Ban myself button on user profiles--MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/32299/ban-myself-button-in-user-profiles)

Code and inspiration from [Wikipedia's version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_User_scripts/Scripts/WikiBreak_Enforcer)

This userscript bans you from the site till a certain date, which you must edit in.even while logged out.

### Installation

- [Save this file as ban.user.js](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/ban.user.js) [Chrome/(Firefox+Greasemonkey) only]
- Change the date variable in the file to the end of the ban
- Set `whileLoggedOut` to `true` if you want to break StackOverflow even while logged out.
- Install the userscript. See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/ban.user.js)